# Can't connect to MySQL server with GoDaddy but can connect in MySQL Workbench

Tags: php, mysql

I've been using a GoDaddy hosted site to connect to a MySQL server with PHP and then populate a table with the query. We just recently switched over to a new MySQL server and now I am not able to connect. All I get is this error message:

```
    Database connection error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 
    '54.203.51.124' (110)(2003)
```

The only difference between this server and the old one is the IP. The user, password, and name are all the same. I'm able to connect fine using MySQL Workbench but with PHP on the GoDaddy site. I've added the website IP address to the firewall and it didn't change anything. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Sorry, I should have clarified that this is a remote connection and not local.

Comment: Try this resource: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html Probably the user permission? `GRANT ALL ON... TO user@yournewIP...`

Comment: Maybe your new MySQL server only allows localhost connections and not remote ones.

Comment: GoDaddy does not allow remote database connectivity. `Unfortunately we do not allow remote MySQL access with our hosting accounts. This includes external connections to our MySQL databases. This also includes outgoing connections to another database.
` are you using a GoDaddy VPS for your website?

Comment: Except for he stated that he can use MySQL Workbench to access it. So this is incorrect. I would look at mysql user credentials and then for code typos.

Comment: @JoshuaBlevins If he is connecting to a remote MySQL server that is not on GoDaddy, His GoDaddy hosted website can not. GoDaddy limits port access on their hosting accounts. Contact GoDaddy support, they will more than likely recommend a VPS that you can configure the IPTABLES with. If he created the MySQL database on GoDaddy's CPanel with the same hosting account, he should be fine. But since he said "different MySQL server", I presume not on the same hosted account by GoDaddy.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Why would a MySQL Workbench connection work on the same server that rejected his programmed connection though? At the end of the day its the same method of connecting.

Comment: His MySQL server is not rejecting the connection. PHP is unable to connect since the port is being blocked by the web host (GoDaddy). It would be the same as if you were to set your PC firewall to block outgoing port 3306. Your PC would not be able to access any default MySQL server remotely. If it was MySQL user domain based, (`user@localhost, user@domain.com, user@1.1.1.1`) he would get invalid credentials error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify. Where, on the network, is your MySQL server and your Workbench. We already know your php program (web site) is on GoDaddy.

Comment: @fyrye The old database server was not on GaDaddy and I was able to connect to it without a problem. Then we set up a new server that used the same username, password, and db name but, obviously a new IP address. So I don't see how it could be a code type because all I needed to change was the IP address for the variable in PHP. It must be getting rejected by the server firewall somewhere but I'm certain that I allowed access to the GoDaddy site already.

Comment: Are you using a GoDaddy VPS or shared web hosting?

Comment: @fyrye Web hosting. But I'm confused as to how that would be the issue when all I'm doing is changing the database IP address I'm connecting to

Comment: @mBurs A VPS would have additional firewall settings you would need to configure to allow for the remote connectivity. How exactly did you add the GoDaddy web server IP to your MySQL server firewall?

Comment: @fyrye Yeah I'm using economy hosting so it's not free. I already added the database IP to the remote MySQL part of the cPanel. The adding of the GoDaddy IP to the MySQL firewall was done by the third party company that manages the database. I'll check in with them to see if there's anything else they can do but I believe they've done all they can on their end.